# Bottom navigation menu items showing filled color. I want to display the exact icons that I added in the drawable folder

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android, android-bottomnav

The way that I have done in the code section.
dynamically generted menu code.

```
 for(int i = 0;i<menuDetails.size();i++){
        int res_id = this.getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+menuDetails.get(i).getMenu_icon(), null, this.getPackageName());
        navigation.getMenu()
                .add(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, menuDetails.get(i).getTitle())
                .setIcon(res_id).setChecked(false)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }
```

**XML file:**

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_selection"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/welcome_text_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        <!--   app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_selection" -->
    </FrameLayout>
```

**nav_selection drawable file:**

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_call"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_case" />
```

output(actually the home button is another layout to fit into the centre, I need the icon like home button in the navigation View).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `BottomNavigationView` the **`app:itemIconTint`** takes a [**`ColorStateList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html).

Each item must define an **`android:color`** attribute, which may be an HTML-style hex color, a reference to a color resource, or -- in API 23 and above -- a theme attribute that resolves to a color.

Instead you are trying to use a `StateListDrawable` and it doesn't work.

The only workaround to avoid tinting and use original icons is to use (`app:itemIconTint="@null"` in the XML doesn't work)

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

In any case I suggest not using it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gabriele. You saved my day :)... it's worked.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove below the line

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/welcome_text_color"
```

Comment: sorry! It's not worked. because this text color is used for the bottom text color.

Comment: I commented both  app:itemIconTint and app:itemTextColor properties. but it won't work.

Comment: try this. <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

Comment: Thank you for the sudden reply @Bhoomika but still showing filled white color icon. :'(

Comment: dynamically I assign the icons in the navigation view. I need the icon like home (please look into the image that I uploaded.)